# Optimisation / COUNT(*) in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query that works

```
$query_list_records = "SELECT COUNT(*)
                         FROM (SELECT comment_id from myl_r_comments
                                WHERE release_id=? LIMIT ? OFFSET ?) A";
```

This does COUNT all rows from the 2nd SELECT.

But for optimisation purposes,
why does the following line not work?

```
$query_list_records = "SELECT COUNT(*)
                         FROM myl_r_comments
                        WHERE release_id=? LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
```

I figure, for a lot number of rows, returning only the COUNT value is nicer than returning a lot of rows (one column selected) and then counting them.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: In what way does the second query 'not work'?

Comment: Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is not good. I'm talking about your first query. Add an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @ypercube: Why, if the purpose is merely to count the results in the outer query?

Comment: i think it does not need to be ordered since it merely counts the results WHERE release_id=? (value) and looks for how many results there are LIMIT 5 from OFFSET (so more 5 or less than 5 if last query)

Comment: ..but you're right @ypercube, the next query, where I display the results (actually send them via AJAX as JSON object), I do order them with ORDER BY

Comment: @eggyal: Oh my bad. It's one of those rare cases, where this is used just to count the rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first version, the `LIMIT` is applied and then the `COUNT(*)` is taken of the result:  e.g. the subquery returns *X* records, which are limited to *Y*, and `COUNT(*)` in the outer query returns *Y*.

In the second version, the `COUNT(*)` of all the records is taken and then the `LIMIT` is applied (but there's only one, aggregated record to limit): so *X* is the sole record returned (but the `OFFSET` might cause it to be excluded from the resultset).

You could instead do:

```
SELECT LEAST(GREATEST(COUNT(*) - ?, 0), ?) from myl_r_comments WHERE release_id=?
```

Comment: you mean there's no other way (optimised such as RAM or speed) ?

Comment: i see, so my line is ok as getting the results

Comment: ..cause I actually count the results from the complex line...thanks

Comment: thanks for the alternative, i'll stick with using what I have :) but I like that you cleared out why the 2nd one does not work